# Separating massive character element in a list as its own list (R)

Tags: r

I'm currently working with a list of adjectives from rcorpora that looks like this when I call `corpora("words/adjs")`:

```
$description
[1] "A list of English adjectives."

$adjs
  [1] "Aristotelian"      "Arthurian"         "Bohemian"          "Brethren"          "Mosaic"           
  [6] "Oceanic"           "Proctor"           "Terran"            "Tudor"             "abroad"
```

There are 1000 words in `$adjs` but for brevity I only put the first 10. I want to individually save all of the adjectives as their own element in a new list, because the way it is now `$adjs` is the second element in list `words/adjs` and a massive character, according to R when I do `class(adjectives$adjs)`. My goal is to be able to randomly go through this new list of adjectives, pick one out, and then use that in my code, but I'm having trouble creating this list of separate, discrete elements. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. To pick one random adjective from `adjectives$adjs` just try `sample(adjectives$adjs, 1)`. You can assign `my_vec <- adjective$adjs` if you need the words in a separate vector.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my_adj <- corpora("words/adjs")$adjs
```

The corpora package looks like it gives you a nested list (first list is description second list is the adjectives). Nested lists are tough to work with so I like to pull objects out by name or index.

If you need to know if you're working with a nested list use the str(...) function, like this:

```
str(corpora("words/adjs"))
```

This will give you a good summary of your R object and then you can dig in and pull out what you need. str(...) is a great function for all objects, not just lists!

Comment: Yes, I'm definitely working with a nested list here which is super frustrating. It's returning this when i use the str() function: `$ adjs       : chr [1:961] "Aristotelian" "Arthurian" "Bohemian" "Brethren" ...`, is there any way to go through the second list item and separate each word into its own item?

Comment: What do you mean "separate each word into its own item?" With the my_adj object in the code above you can call each word using it's index, such as my_adj[10] or my_adj[20:30]. If you want to randomly sample them use the sample(...) function.